# Python was not found after closing commandline. Windows opens app store when I type python

Tags: python

I have downloaded and installed python from [here](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.6/python-3.10.6-amd64.exe).

Then I restarted and opened a commandline and typed

```
python --version
```

I recorded all my actions, so I can post a screenshot of that:

[image]

It works and shows the version number.

Then I performed the following steps to install Jupyter because I want to use a local runtime with Google Colab:

In the Windows commandline (not in the Python window!!), I type this:

```
pip install virtualenv
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
virtualenv opencv (I guess I can choose a random name here because we will not be using OpenCV, right? But for simplicity, I keep this name now)
I CD to c:\users\MYUSERNAME\opencv\Scripts
activate.bat
pip install numpy
python -m pip install jupyter

Now my browser opens this page: http://localhost:8888/tree
Now I click "New" and "Python 3 (ipykernel)"
```

Now I want to install the extension jupyter_http_over_ws.
I type:

```
pip install jupyter_http_over_ws
```

Nothing shows up when I type text on the keyboard. It looks like this:

[image]

Because I want to be able to type again, I close the command line and open it again.

Now I type again:

```
pip install jupyter_over_http_ws
```

It says

```
The command "pip" has been misspelt oder was not found.
```

Because I have no idea what is happening, I type:

```
python --version
```

I am expecting that it shows the version number like before.

But instead it shows

```
"Python was not found."
```

Why is that?

ps: When I type "python", it starts the Microsoft App Store and offers me to download it:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: You just need to add Python to your path.  Do you know how to edit the environment variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if you add your python installation path to the environment variables?
https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-add-python-to-path-variable-in-windows

Don't forget to restart Windows after adding the path!